# Table 'myDB.delayed_jobs' doesn't exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I am trying to use the gem delayed_job from https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job.

I put gem 'delayed_job_active_record' in my Gemfile and did bundle install.

Then, I did:

```
rails generate delayed_job
rake db:migrate
```

I believe the migration was supposed to create a table delayed_jobs, but it did not.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3+, you need the following two in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'delayed_job'
gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
```

Then change your generate to:

```
rails g delayed_job:active_record
rake db:migrate
```

Read more info [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) and [here](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job).